# creating instances of classes haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

So I have this class:

```
class Collection c where
    empty :: c key value
    singleton :: key -> value -> c key value
    insert :: Ord key => key -> value -> c key value -> c key value
    looKup :: Ord key => key -> c key value -> Maybe value
    delete :: Ord key => key -> c key value -> c key value
    keys :: c key value -> [key]
    keys x = map fst $ toList x
    values :: c key value -> [value]
    values c = map snd $ toList c
    toList :: c key value -> [(key, value)]
    fromList :: Ord key => [(key,value)] -> c key value
    fromList [] = empty
    fromList ((k, v):xs) = insert k v (fromList xs)
```

Why is this

```
instance Collection (PairList k v) where
```

a bad instantion of the class
and this:

```
instance Collection PairList where
```

is a good one ?
I know that when making maybe an instance of `Eq`, this is how haskell does it:

```
instance Eq (Maybe m) where  
    Just x == Just y = x == y  
    Nothing == Nothing = True  
    _ == _ = False
```

So instantiations accept parameters... So why is the first one like so ?

Comment: Do you understand why `instance Functor Maybe` is correct rather than `instance Functor (Maybe a)`?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with "kinds", there's a good introductory write-up in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo). (Note that the kind `*` is I believe deprecated in some sense and we're supposed to call it `Type` now. But you'll definitely see people refer to `*` often enough, including in @chepner's answer, so it's useful to know that that means the same thing.)

Answer (score 6):

Based on how `c` is used, `Collection` requires something of kind `* -> * -> *`.

```
> :k Collection
Collection :: (* -> * -> *) -> Constraint
```

`PairList k v`, though, has kind `*`.

`Eq`, on the other hand, expects something of kind `*`, which is exactly what `Maybe m` is.

```
> :k Eq
Eq :: * -> Constraint
```

(`Maybe` itself has kind `* -> *`, but applying it to a type variable produces something of kind `*`.)

Answer (score 5):

The thing you put in the instance head will be substituted for the class variable everywhere. So, if we combine

```
class Collection c where
    empty :: c key value
    -- and other stuff, too, of course
```

and

```
instance Collection (PairList k v)
```

we get the type

```
    empty :: (PairList k v) key value
```

which doesn't make a lot of sense. But if we combine the class declaration with

```
instance Collection PairList
```

then we get the type

```
    empty :: PairList key value
```

which makes sense just fine.